# Which group should a user be a part of in order to make API call to Oracle Cloud Infrastructure?

Tags: oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle-rest-data-services

While making Rest API calls I am getting this error

> Your credentials could not be authenticated: "Credentials are
>   missing. You will not be permitted access until your credentials can be
>   verified."

I have cross-verified my private key and apiKey, all the credentials are correct. Still, I am getting this error. If anyone could help me how this error could be resolved, it would be really great.

Answer (score 1):

Can you share some more details? For example, which API/service are you trying to access, what is the endpoint, your tenancy id, and most importantly opc-request-id if you have one for the failed call.

Please engage support team to create a support ticket too.